# slide a page in web application

Tags: javascript, css, iphone

I want to slide left/right a page with some animation. (Just like iphone apps)

```
<body>
    <div id="page1">
        <!-- Full screen content  with a button at bottom, on click I want to show #page2 but with slide animation. #page1 will slide-out left and #page2 will slide-in from right-->
    </div>
    <div id="page2">
        <!-- Full screen content with a button at bottom, on click It will show page1 with slide animation -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a "selected" class for the selected page and a "page" class for every page, try something along these lines:

```
.page {
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;

    -moz-transition:1s left;
    -o-transition:1s left;
    -webkit-transition:1s left;
    transition:1s left;
}

.page.selected {
    left: 0;
}
```

This will work on Webkit, Firefox 4 and Opera (don't remember version) and will degrade gracefully on non-supporting browsers (they'll just go from start to end in one step).

Comment: Can you please check this page http://204.93.167.12/AppMy/EcoHome/testpage.html   and click on Main Floor, slide animation is not working.

Comment: From what I quickly saw in the Web inspector (ctrl+alt+I) it looks like the slide animation **is** working (I manually added the class, since by clicking it wasn't added which looks like a problem with your JS), just the page is not shown. One guess would be that it's a z-index issue. If it's not that, a simplified test case would help.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is useful for animating HTML elements.

[This is a good tutorial](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions) about the various different methods of sliding using jQuery:

Also, you might want to look at some sort of carousel plug-in and check out how they work because they do very similar things to what you want:

- [Google search for 'jQuery carousel'](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&xhr=t&q=jquery+carousel)
- [jQuery Carousel plug-in by Thomas Lanciaux](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm)