# How do I do mobile animation perfectly?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, css, touch

As you can see my last **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217904/javascript-animation-lags-on-iphone)** didn't attract the community but I managed to get that animation on iPhone working via CSS3 transitions pretty great.

I normalized my code to use CSS3 animations now. This is little better than what I saw using JavaScript. But still the animation lags on the device. I have many DIVs inside `<body>` and only one at a time would be visible and all other are hidden.

If you look at this picture, these are 4 DIVs but the second DIV is being currently shown on the device. Now I want you to please write me some code to understand how can I apply movement of DIVs along x-axis as only one would be shown?

[image]

**UPDATED**

The code I have right now is...

```
function slideLeftTo(to, after) {
    var page = $(to);
    var current = $(".current");

    if (page.length < 1) return;
    if (current.length < 1) return; 

    if (page.attr("id") == current.attr("id")) return;

    var endX = current.width();

    page.css({ top: "0px", left: endX + "px", display: "block" });
    current.css({ top: "0px", left: "0px", display: "block" });

    setTimeout(function() {
        current.css("left", -endX + "px");
        page.css("left", "0px");
    }, 50);

    setTimeout(after, 850);
}

function slideRightTo(to, after) {
    var page = $(to);
    var current = $(".current");

    if (page.length < 1) return;
    if (current.length < 1) return; 

    if (page.attr("id") == current.attr("id")) return;

    var endX = current.width();

    page.css({ top: "0px", left: -endX + "px", display: "block" });

    setTimeout(function() {
        current.css("left", endX + "px");
        page.css("left", "0px");
    }, 50);

    setTimeout(after, 850);
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far? What have you tried? SO is not the place for unpaid consultant work, it's the place to go for help in doing the work yourself.

Comment: I have posted a link if you see.

Comment: You mean the link to your other question? Why ask it yet another time then? What has changed, what does your new code look like?

Comment: The old post shows what I have tried and this is working but lags. I have converted that code into CSS and if you are going to help, you know what it's supposed to be in CSS. You can imagine what it could be in CSS so the reason I asked to write you guys code because I will then compare what's wrong with my code. This will also help me get other ideas too.

Comment: This is not obvious that my code will be wrong so there can be approach problem.

Comment: Good luck getting help, I for one will not write code just so you can compare it to your own code. Out of here.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I want you to please write me some code to understand how can I
>   apply movement of DIVs along x-axis as only one would be shown?

This answers why you're last question didn't get answered!

You can't just expect your code to be wrote on here. Maybe show us what you already have tried, we can  show where you went wrong. People aren't here to do your job for you.

Comment: I have posted a link if you see. The link to old post which has code shown.

Comment: Ok, so do you need to know how to do it in css animations or is using jQuery animations sufficient?

Comment: I see your code. Do you want a pure CSS3 alternative? Yours isn't css animations

Comment: did you get a chance to help?

Comment: In the mean time, I am going to try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274462/slide-a-page-in-web-application

Comment: that should work fine. i was going to write you a working version in my lunch break today, so let me know in the next couple of hours if you've resolved it

Comment: I have now complete CSS animation reading that post I found. What I put is still lagging. Do you have gtalk to talk so I show you what's wrong and where?